# Google maps geocoding. Function to display lat and lng in 2 textboxws

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, maps

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html

Hi, This is my first post.

I am trying to edit the code in the link above to display the latitude and longitude of the address in 2 texboxes so that I can then save it to a mysql database. I will then use this lat.lng to the display the location of that user when someone if viewing there profile

I would really appreciate any help as I have being struggling with this for a number of weeks

Answer (score 1):

The response from the genocide method call should return an object of which one property will be a google.maps.LatLng object.  You can call the .lat() & .lng() getters on the class and assig. The values to the text boxes